# jQuery(.Mobile) not firing properly in Android browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

jQuery code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#stid_status_msg').hide();
$('.SpeedTestId').blur(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var stid = $('.SpeedTestId').val();
    var postString = 'stid=' + stid;
/*  $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url:"inc/check_stid.inc.php", 
        type:'POST',
        data:postString,
        success:function(msg) {
            $('#stid_status_msg').html(msg);
            $('#stid_status_msg').show();
        },
        error:function(error) {
            $('#stid_status_msg').html('<font color="red">Error submitting results!' + error + '</font>');
            $('#stid_status_msg').show();
        }
    });*/
    $.get("inc/check_stid.inc.php", { stid: stid }, function(msg) {
            $('#stid_status_msg').html(msg);
            $('#stid_status_msg').show();
    });
});
```

The commented out `$.ajax()` method is what I was trying originally, but quickly discovered `$.get()` was a better method for what I was trying to do. But regardless of which method I use the code works fine in desktop browsers (FF,IE,Chrome), but does not complete successfully in the Android browser.

When I use `$.ajax()`, and I test in the Android browser it first hangs for several seconds, and then the error callback fires and I get:

Error submitting results! [object][object]

I should also note that when I enable the java console in the Android browser, it does not indicate any errors with the JS.

So it occurs to me that the script is not able to find/load `inc/check_stid.inc.php` for some reason. But why only in the Android browser?

Obviously I'm a jQuery newbie, and I appreciate any insight you folks can provide.

**Edit**

I installed FF on my android and the code works fine there as well. Whatever I am encountering is specific to the android browser. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

An `error` callback for a jQuery AJAX request will be passed the following arguments:

1. `jqXHR`: the XHR object associated with the AJAX request
2. `textStatus`: a string error message
3. `errorThrown`: an object containing error specific information

You are trying to output the `jqXHR` as though it was a string, not an object (like it is). To get a meaningful error message, try this:

```
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        //only log the objects if the current browser has a console.log function
        if (typeof console == 'object' && typeof console.log == 'function') { console.log(jqXHR); console.log(errorThrown); }

        $('#stid_status_msg').html('<font color="red">Error submitting results!' + textStatus + '</font>').show();
    }
```

Docs for `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I had attempted to understand the jqXHR object to get meaningful error output, but failed. This helps clear things up a bit for me, thank you. However, now it simply outputs 'Error submitting results!' after the same short hang described above. Any other ideas to get to the bottom of this? Thank you in advance.